# UIWebview textfield not saving value enter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i want to save uiwebvew textfield enter value 
[image]

and log this html (with entered textfield values )

i tried below methods nut none providing me value i have entered

```
 testHTML = [self.webViewstringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];


NSLog(@"TESTHTML ->> %@",testHTML);




    testHTML = [self.webViewstringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];


NSLog(@"TESTHTML ->> %@",testHTML);
```

Comment: my html has too many ID which are random , how i can get id of them , and want to reload logged HTML ( i tried but no giving me entered values )

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML will have a form element, access the textfield by its ID, in this case the form element has an id="username"

```
NSString *value = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"escape(document.getElementById(\"username\").value);"];
```

Use a Chrome or Safari browser inspector to inspect the HTML content and to figure out the best way to access the data field you are after.

You must have access to the HTML content to access the textfield by some ID, element tag, or element name. Adjust your document call as needed:

document.getElementsByClassName("username")[0];
or
document.getElementsByTagName("textfield")[0];

Comment: my html has too many ID which are random , how i can get id of them